# How to set up SSH Agent Forwarding in node.js (simple-ssh module)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh

I am new to this node.js and using module simple-ssh for executing shell commands from my windows to remote server.
Whenever I run my code, the console curses me with `[Error: Authentication failure. Available authentication methods: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive]`.
I have already put an RSA private-key file, and set the `Windows ENV variable` `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`. But still it keeps giving the error.
Below is the code snippet which I wrote for simple-ssh:

```
var ssh = new SSH({
                    host: sshHost,
                    user: 'root',
                    timeout: 11000000,
                    key: require('fs').readFileSync("D:/Keys_pair_prvt_pub/rsa_key"),
                    agent: process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK,
                    agentForward: true
                });
```

When I am trying to `SSH` the remote from my windows cmd-prompt, it is giving me error:

```
$> ssh -A <myRemote.host.com>
ssh : The term 'ssh' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Am I missing anything? If yes, then how do I overcome this ?
Any help will be appreciated :)
Thanks.

Comment: How is this related to PowerShell?

Comment: because SSH command is not working in powershell. Do i need to install anything to make the ssh -A command run from windows powershell ?

Comment: PowerShell and CMD (Command Prompt) are different things. Also, why would you expect a node.js variable to work in PowerShell (or CMD)?

Comment: Is it safe to assume you are using bash on Windows and not the normal Windows command prompt or similar? Typically `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is set by the OpenSSH agent, which would only be the case with bash on Windows, where you might actually have such a thing available. However, as far as just the authentication issue goes, are you sure that the **private** (not public) key at that path works for authenticating with that server?

Comment: yes i am sure i have put the ras-public key on my remote host and rsa-private key file on my local. i created this public-private pair on my remote first. 
Today i tried to install cygwin for this issue, and tried to create the public-private pair on my local. but cygwin again is throwing error that cygssp-0.dll is missing. i reinstalled it but no help. i googled and found that antivirus blocks this file. but in my case, my local mcachine is my office desk, i am not authorized to play around with antivirus settings. I am stuck. i tried getting the portable cygwin, but cannot find the link.

Comment: Did you add your key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the server?

Comment: yes sure I did.

Answer (score 1):

Your key needs to be added to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the server for your key to work.

mscdex npm package SSH2, which simple-ssh wraps, has this in the docs for using ssh.agent on windows:

`agent - string - Path to ssh-agent's UNIX socket for ssh-agent-based user authentication. **Windows users: set to 'pageant' for authenticating with Pageant or (actual) path to a cygwin "UNIX socket."**